# Cassandra error code=2200 [invalid query] message="unknown column referenced in primary key for materialized view 'op'"

Tags: cassandra, materialized-views

I am new to Cassandra, I am trying to create a materialized view. But it is not working.
Below is the table and materialized view definition along with the error code-

### Table

```
CREATE TABLE my_keyspace.my_table (
    customerno text,
    operatorname text,
    customername text,
    operatorno text,
PRIMARY KEY (customerno));
```

### Materialized view

```
CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW op
AS SELECT operatorname,operatorno 
FROM my_keyspace.my_table
WHERE operatorname IS NOT NULL AND customerno IS NOT NULL 
PRIMARY KEY (operatorname, customerno);
```

### ERROR Message while creating materialized view

```
invalidrequest: error from server: code=2200 [invalid query] 
message="unknown column customerno referenced in primary key
for materialized view 'op'"
```

---

`customerno` is a primary key in the base table.

Answer (score 1):

That error is indicating that `customerno` also needs to be in the `SELECT` clause from the base table.  This should work:

```
> CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW op AS SELECT operatorname, operatorno, customerno
  FROM stackoverflow.customer_table 
  WHERE operatorname IS NOT NULL AND customerno IS NOT NULL
  PRIMARY KEY (operatorname, customerno);
```

Answer (score 1):

To add to Aaron's answer, it seems like you're running an older version of Cassandra.

In later versions of 3.0+ and 3.11, all primary key columns of the base table are automatically included so your `CREATE` statement should've worked.

For example if I run it on C* 3.0.10 (without `customerno` in the `SELECT` clause):

```
CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW op
  AS SELECT operatorname,operatorno 
  FROM my_keyspace.my_table
  WHERE operatorname IS NOT NULL AND customerno IS NOT NULL 
  PRIMARY KEY (operatorname, customerno);
```

A `DESCRIBE` on the view returns:

```
cqlsh> DESCRIBE MATERIALIZED VIEW my_keyspace.op;

CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW my_keyspace.op AS
    SELECT operatorname, customerno, operatorno
    FROM my_keyspace.my_table
    WHERE operatorname IS NOT NULL AND customerno IS NOT NULL
    PRIMARY KEY (operatorname, customerno)
    WITH CLUSTERING ORDER BY (customerno ASC)
    ...
```

with `customerno` automatically included:

```
    ...
    SELECT operatorname, customerno, operatorno
    ...
```

Cheers!